# who to give unique name to the output of write.csv files in a user function?

Tags: r

Following is my example function

```
  op.try.df<- function(df){
      x1 <- bind_rows(full_v_gu,summarise(df,across(where(is.numeric),sum)))
      x2 <- x1%>%
            mutate("Perc"=round(Composite_Score/MAX*100,0))
      x3 <- x2[,c("Name" ,"Total","Score","Perc")]
      write.csv(x3,"df.csv")
      x3
    }
```

How do I provide output file name based on the input data frame name?
I want my output file (df.csv) to have the same name of the data frame, for example if my input file is named 'new' op.try.df(new), then how do I get a file name 'new.csv' in the folder? currently all my output files are named df.csv.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At the beginning of the function, use `substitute` with `deparse` to extract the input name

```
op.try.df <- function(df){
      nm1 <- paste0(deparse(substitute(df)),'.csv')
      x1 <- bind_rows(full_v_gu,summarise(df,across(where(is.numeric),sum)))
      x2 <- x1%>%
            mutate("Perc"=round(Composite_Score/MAX*100,0))
      x3 <- x2[,c("Name" ,"Total","Score","Perc")]
      write.csv(x3, nm1)
      x3
    }
```

-testing

```
>  testing.df<- function(df){
+        nm1 <- paste0(deparse(substitute(df)),'.csv')
+        nm1
+      }
>      
>      testing.df(mtcars)
[1] "mtcars.csv"
```